# Compression Algorithm to compress text files

Tags: algorithm, compression, text-files, aes

I am doing my graduation project which is arabic language Compression and encryption.

The Encryption algorithm is done using AES and it works very well.

But my problem is the Compression I don't know what algorithms I use what is the most easy to implement and has  a good output performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is important that you FIRST compress and THEN encrypt.
otherwise, you won't be able to compress.

that said, use whatever compression you can get, like xz, bzip2, gzip, ...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old answer, but it feels like there is an insufficient answer with regards to what compression algorithm the asker should use, hence this answer.

If I were you I would use an existing library such as [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/), which has been implemented in multiple languages.

Using this library you can decide if you want to use the deflate algorithm or the gzip one. The difference between these two is nicely described in their [FAQ](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq39).

Hope this helps.